# Javascript: How to replace certain characters from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to get a set of names from URL as URL parameter.

```
var url_arrays = [],url_param;
var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
        {
            url_param = url[i].split('=');
            url_arrays.push(url_param[0]);
            url_arrays[url_param[0]] = url_param[1];
        }
var temp = decodeURIComponent(url_arrays[2]).split(','||' ');
```

but this way I am getting output like this

`[jon` `Ned` `Brian` `Sam]`

How to remove the opening & closing bracket ?

`replace` method is there in javascript but in that I can't replace a set of characters like `str.replace('['||']','')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `regex` is wrong.

```js
var str = '[jon Ned Brian Sam]';
str = str.replace(/\[|\]/g, '');
alert(str);
```

OR,

```js
var str = '[jon Ned Brian Sam]';
str = str.replace('[', '').replace(']', '');
alert(str);
```

OR,

you can use `substr` methods.

```js
var str = '[jon Ned Brian Sam]';
str = str.substr(1, str.length - 2);
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove leading and trailing square brackets with  the following regex:

```js
var str = '[jon Ned Brian Sam]';
str = str.replace(/^\[|\]$/g, '');
document.write(str);
```

the anchors `^` (string start) and `$` (string end) make sure we only remove the brackets at the leading/trailing positions in the input string.